# Display month names on bokeh x-axis

Tags: python, bokeh

Does anyone know how I can overwrite the x-axis values to display the months of the year in bokeh?

The graph looks well, and is working as intended, but the x-axis shows numbers up to 12 (as you would expect) - whereas I would like to override this and have it display the month names. It's plotting data that comes in this format:

```
{u'amencke': [15, 8, 9, 49, 39, 42, 40, 23, 33, 0, 0, 0], ....}
```

Using a simple line plot:

```
for x, y in data.iteritems():
        pMonth = Line(data, title="Sea Bass caught", tools=False, xlabel='Month', ylabel='No. Caught',\
                width=1300, height=600, legend='top_right')
```

If possible - I'd like the y-axis to display the months - for example the data in this array:

```
months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
```

Any ideas? Bokeh has nice documentation but I couldn't find a way of doing this.

Cheers, Arthur

Comment: `p.xaxis.formatter = DatetimeTickFormatter(format="%b")`?

Comment: @Alex.S That's what i was hoping for - but it seems that a Line graph does not have an x or y axis element that you can customize. If I use the method you suggested like such `pMonth.xaxis.formatter = DatetimeTickFormatter(formats=dict(months=['%b']))` I will see something like `'Chart' object has no attribute 'xaxis'` (there is no a-axis attribute with another name). Thanks anyway - I will look into the make_axis function or use a different chart type. Arthur

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simplified solution

```py
data = [15, 8, 9, 49, 39, 42, 40, 23, 33, 0, 0, 0] 
months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]

p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=200)
x = months
y = data
p = figure(x_range = x)
p.line(x,y)
p.circle(x,y, fill_color="white", size=8)
show(p)
```

Providing the categories as the x_range or y_range explicitly helps. [Bokeh Doc](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/categorical.html)